# Filtering on message from: address not working with Graph API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph REST API to retrieve messages in my Outlook inbox. It's working for the most part, but filtering on the from address is playing up.

My call:

```
GET /me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address+eq+'sender@myaddr.com'
```

This returns an empty list. However, if I remove the filter to get the full list, I can see that there are messages from the email address 'sender@myaddr.com'.

If I change the `eq` condition to `startsWith`:

```
GET /me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=startsWith(from/emailAddress/address,'sender@myaddr.com')
```

then it works as intended. Is there something wrong with my original filter? The `from/emailAddress/address` field is definitely just 'sender@myaddr.com' with nothing else.

This is with both the v1.0 and beta API versions.

Comment: Try this way `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq 'shiva@nishantsingh.live'` Don't use + . it worked for me.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma the actual URL looks something like `...%2faddress%20eq%20%27sender%40myaddr.com%27`, ie it's all URL-encoded. The `+` is just to make the code legible

Comment: Also, just to clarify that this is personal Outlook (outlook.com), not the business version

Comment: @HongOoi - AFAIK, it should not make the difference its Outlook/hotmail or m365 account, but i havent tested with prior one. I jsut tested with M365 account and its working for me. Make sure that url encoding is correct, if not it may lead to the issue

Comment: A couple small updates. Filtering on the name works, ie `from/emailAddress/name eq 'whatever'`. Using `gt` or `ge` on the address returns random results, either the correct result or everything