# msgraph - endsWith filter method not working query my OneDrive

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a method that filters my one drive items using msgraph its working for most of the cases except `endsWith` method when I passing `'endsWith(name,\'.png\')'` as param for my method it's throwing an error

```
export async function getFileByFilter(
  msgraph_client: Client,
  filter: string
): Promise<MicrosoftGraph.DriveItem[]> {
const result = await msgraph_client
    .api(
      `/drives/${drive_id}/items:/children`
    )
    .filter(filter)
    .get();
 return result.value as MicrosoftGraph.DriveItem[];
}
```

Ref:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter

**UPDATE**
the other filter methods are working just fine like (`startsWith` , `contains`)

**The error**

with `startsWith` method it returns an empty array in case I am looking for not exists
example: `$filter=startsWith(displayName,'J')`
with `endsWith` method it throw `Not Found - 404` in all cases even I am sure there are match of what I am looking for

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "Item not found",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-08-24T13:07:07",
            "request-id": "f3d453ee-0596-4a41-9647-a8a0826dd918",
            "client-request-id": "b52033e0-2243-e812-fbb2-07bf21566be5"
        }
    }
}
```

you can play with its explore
Ref:https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: I find that filtering in Graph can be unpredictably glitchy. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257113/filtering-on-message-from-address-not-working-with-graph-api), to do with filtering Outlook emails

Comment: oh I see but all other filter methods are working like (startsWith , contains) that's a bit confusing for me

Comment: Would you kindly share the error and the request-id so we can look into this?

Comment: Not Found - 404  even when using startsWith with empty result its return empty array